# Dojo Rich Editor in Django: Correct admin.py Settings?

Tags: django, dojo, django-admin, rich-text-editor

I'm building a blog, with models "Post" and "Image" like so:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    text = models.TextField(max_length=10000)

class Image(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='images')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d')
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=1000,blank=True)
```

I've been trying to implement the Dojo rich editor in my admin site by following the example
here:

http://lazutkin.com/blog/2011/mar/13/using-dojo-rich-editor-djangos-admin/

However, there's some kind of interference between settings in my admin.py file that is keeping me from registering both the rich editor and a ModelAdmin class for uploading images associated with an instance of "Post."  If I use the following code in my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib.admin import site, ModelAdmin
import models

class CommonMedia:
    js = (
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js',
      'editor.js',
    )
    css = {
      'all': ('editor.css',),
    }

site.register(models.Post,
    Media = CommonMedia,
)
```

The rich text editor shows up fine.  But if I add some code for image uploading fields, like so:

```
from blogs.models import Post,Image
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin import site, ModelAdmin
import models


class CommonMedia:
  js = (
    'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6.0/dojo/dojo.xd.js',
    'editor.js',
  )
  css = {
    'all': ('editor.css',),
  }

class PostImageInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Image
    extra = 5

class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [PostImageInline]

site.register(models.Post,
    list_display = ('text',),
    search_fields = ['text',],
    Media = CommonMedia,
)

admin.site.unregister(Post)

admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

the rich editor doesn't show up.  I'm guessing this is due to the "admin.site.unregister(Post)" line, but if I don't use that I get the error, "The model Post is already registered."  If instead I remove both that line and the "Post" from "admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)", I get the error: "'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable".  Does anyone know how to resolve this so I can have both my PostAdmin and rich editor on the same page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/home/guillaume/mysite/blogs/static/editor.js` is incorrect, you should provide an URL here. Probably, `/static/editor.js`

Also, use web inspector for chrome/safari or firebug for firefox to catch some errors in the console.

Comment: Which prefix is used for the URL?  Is it the STATIC_URL prefix, or another one listed in settings.py?

Comment: Which "another one" do you mean?

Comment: Hi ilvar, I fixed this part and got the rich editor to work (see above); thank you very much for your help with that.  My problem now is getting it to work while also registering a ModelAdmin class that allows me to upload images.  Any ideas?

Comment: Why don't you put that media definition inside PostAdmin itself? Why do you need to register Post model twice?

Comment: Because that would make too much sense.  I knew I was missing something silly!  I guess I was just confused by the syntax used by lazutkin in his example (site.register() with what appears to be multiple kinds of arguments).  Anyway thanks for the help with this; everything now works perfectly.